# Shielding from inductive charging in simple PCB

Tags: shielding, wireless-charging

I am going to design a fairly simple binary LED wrist watch. For a cool feature and a good learning experience I want it to have wireless charging capabilities so I purchased this wireless charging set from adafruit [link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1407)

Unfortunately this set comes with no documentation and I can't even find who made it. 
I'm pretty new to wireless charging so I'm wondering what sort of shielding will I need to protect the other electronics on my board? I am thinking I'll put the coil on the bottom of the PCB and everything else on top. Will something as simple as a layer of aluminum foil do the trick?

I've done some research but everything I've read so far is pretty complex (and $$) for what I'd like to do for such a simple project.

Comment: 1st lesson in EE, don't buy anything with crappy or non-existant documentation. So how are you going to fit that coil in your (presumably expanding) wristwatch?

Comment: Its actually not that big. About the size of an apple watch. For $10 this couldn't be passed up!

Comment: I would put some foil between the coils and see how much it lowers the power transfer. If foil isn't looking promising (mild attenuation would be 1/8th of the power) I would try a ferrite shield. I have adhesive flexible ferrite sheet lying around for when I need to tinker with EMC compliance issues.